# Using django-admin after cookiecutter-django setup

Tags: django-admin, cookiecutter-django

When I enter `django-admin` on the command line, I get a list of allowed commands and then an error line:

> Note that only Django core commands are listed as settings are not properly configured (error: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.).

If I try to add a `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable to fix this, I get the message that `confit.settings.local` is not a valid Python module.

Comment: Also, this is a pycharm setup. I entered pycharm yes in the setup. Also, added the environment entries in django/manage.py running config in pycharm.

Comment: The pycharm manage.py interface works without any issues.

Comment: What value, specifically, did you set your `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable to?

Comment: export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = config.settings.local